# The Flash healing factor (new TV series)

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

Is The Flash healing factor ultimate like Wolverine's, or is it limited to a tissue type and/or percentage of damage?

In one of the episodes, Cisco says to Flash "(...) watch out for teeth, because they don't grow back.", which makes me wonder about Flash's healing abilities.

How does it look in the comics as compared to the new TV series?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Barry Allen, in *The Flash*, doesn't have a healing factor in the sense that the term is typically used in comics. He is not able to heal wounds or injuries that normal humans could not.

What he has is *accelerated healing* -- because everything about his biology is accelerated, he heals the same way that a non-metahuman would but it happens more quickly. For example, if a person Barry's age were to fracture a bone in their arm or leg, it would typically take about 6 weeks for it to fully heal. If Barry were to fracture a bone in his arm or leg, it might heal in a matter of days or even hours.

However, if Barry's hand were *cut off*, the bleeding would stop and a stump would grow over the injury very quickly, but he wouldn't regrow a hand the way Wolverine would.

Comment: Idk, the speed force would probably give him a lightning hand or some nonsense.

Comment: @cde Nah, more likely, his accelerated healing would just heal the damaged tissue *between* the hand and his arm, thereby reattaching it. lol

Comment: What, like in blade 2?

Comment: Well, in the TV series Flash don't develop a scar tissue and he can survive falling down from several floors, so it's still little more than just an accelerated healing.

Comment: @oski86: it is the kinetic energy (hence the velocity) that hurts during a fall from several floors. So he may be protected by the Speed Force. I remember in the 90's Flash TV show, the Flash was able to catch bullets without any harm, when he was moving fast enough.

Comment: He also seems to have some other low-level superpowers in the TV show.  He seems to be slightly stronger than he ought to be, and a good bit more durable.  (He takes a lot of hits that would cripple or kill a normal human, and just gets winded.)  There's probably some speed-related explanation, but it helps to remember when understanding how The Flash takes damage.

Comment: @Nerrolken In the pilot, Caitlin explains his extra strength as his muscle cells growing and dividing much faster than a normal person; his resistance to injury (both physical and chemical) is explained in a few different episodes as his cells healing faster than he can sustain damage.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield  She explains his *muscles* that way, but not his extra strength beyond what his muscles would give him.  I'm saying, Barry Allen seems to be stronger than Grant Gustin, even though they (obviously) have the same physique.  Barry seems to be able to (for example) carry people to safety with ease, while a normal human of his size and musculature would have a harder time carrying fully-grown adults.

Comment: @Taladris By matching the bullets velocity and slowing it down in a *really* short amount of space and time, yes -- not like just grabbing/deflecting it, as Superman could (although he could slow it down as well if he wanted to). Still, Barry should really burn his fingers doing things like that (well, the heat probably dissipates into the Speed Force)